# Software Installation Documents

Tags: documentation, standards, ieee

Does anyone know if there is an IEEE standard for software installation instruction documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it not [IEEE 1063](http://standards.ieee.org/reading/ieee/std_public/description/se/1063-2001_desc.html)?

Comment: I had looked at this or something like this, but thought it sounded more like a users manual than installation instructions.  There may not be anything that really fits what I am after.  What I am trying to describe is a document that will list each instruction for installing software along with screen shots of each installation step.  I may be able to adapt this though....gives me something to think about over the weekend.